# What did the pimp mean by 'no rough stuff' in Taxi Driver?

Tags: taxi-driver

During the pimp scene, the pimp tells Travis what he can do:

> You can cum on her, f*** her in the mouth, f*** her in the ass, cum on her face, man. She get your cock so hard she'll make it explode.

And then his next sentence is:

> But no rough stuff, all right?

Is this some intended comedy or pimp meant some real extreme sick shit beyond boundaries or something? She was 12 and a half so maybe pimp cared about her and told all clients 'no rough stuff' but at same time it makes no sense after all that stuff he just listed, it sounded it was pretty rough already.

Comment: `after all that stuff he just listed, it sounded it was pretty rough already` That is very subjective. Without providing examples (for good taste), the sexual entertainment industry goes _well_ beyond what was already listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always viewed it as a disclaimer that they tell to clients so they know there's no kinky stuff allowed, i.e. BDSM or whipping or stuff like that

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I saw the movie, but from the context it seems the intention is to remind the audience how horrible the scenario, the city and the culture shown in the movie are. As you pointed out, the list of things the pimp allows are aggressive and degrading. But the pimp does not consider any of them "rough stuff".

Answer (score 1):

Basically it means don't leave any marks on her that would mean he can't charge as much for her. invariably bruised and beaten women aren't as appealing to men as healthy looking ones, so they can't earn the pimp as much money, this seems to apply to her as well irrespective of her age.

As others had stated that means whipping, hitting and BDSM, the disguesting part is that the pimp most likely says this out of his own greed as opposed to any concern for her wellbeing